# easy issue about Ruby

Tags: ruby

I would like to know what it does:

```
File.open(filename,"r").each_file do |line|
  if (!line.strip.empty? and !line.starts_with?(" "))
   ....
   .....
  end 
end
```

Especially what is`strip`? Thanks for your time!

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-strip

Comment: Also, this is not Rails-specific, just Ruby.

Comment: yes I run it but is complaining about the strip

Comment: fwiw, that code doesn't make too much sense. File.open will yield the file, not a line of that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip removes all the leading and trailing whitespace chars from a string. In essense the code you pasted checks if the sting contains anything apart from whitespaces AND the first symbol is not a space.